# Why do I need an e-mail accaunt to send mails on ruby and don't need such on php?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I used `mail()` command in php and it worked fine without defining any logins and passwords. Now I am learing Ruby on Rails and it's written in guides that I need to configure some e-mail accaunt to be able to send e-mails. Why do I need one on Ruby and don't need any on php? What is difference and what is better?

Comment: Who says you need an email ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

generally speaking you don't need one on rails, anymore than you need one in php. It all depends on your hosting setup. On a well connected server running a local mail server/relay agent you can setup rails to use the local sendmail config, this is normally what php does by default with the mail() command).   see  `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html` specifically section 6.1

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# Defaults to:
# config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
#   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
#   arguments: '-i -t'
# }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-replay@example.com'}
```

There are also configs there for gmail, etc.

I'll add that the reason most tutorials show the email account being used is that they are being run on localhost which there is a good chance isn't well connected and doesn't have a working sendmail config in place. So in order to make it work, and actually see emails from the app, using something like gmail to relay is a safe choice/default.

Comment: I am going to run my own server on Ubuntu. Should I install some local mail server on or should I use g-mail acc? And what should I use on development and tesing on localhost?

Comment: all depends on volume of mail you are going to be delivering. and your experience running mail servers.  Does your domain already have a functioning mail server? will it be accepting inbound email? If yes, using your existing/ running your own would work.  The downside is that setting up  new mail server, and getting the big boys(big sp,freemail provider, etc..) to accept your email can be a challenge .  But if you are sending a high volume of email, gmail with throttle/ban you pretty quickly , so there is that to be mindful of as well.

Comment: As for Dev/testing. you don't want to be sending out email in those environments.  Just just just deliver to a file / log  or to a local array  and test that.  Way easier then round tripping it out to a mail server